# create table in R with subrows

Tags: r, gt

How can I creat a table that looks like the one below using gt in R? Alternatively, instead of a second row per each row (sector), a second column for each period.

I am using GT in the following way but I can find a function to introduce more rows. For instance if my dataframe df4 had more columns, I would like to assing it as a second row to each of the sectors. Or a second column to each period.

```
gt(df4)|>
  cols_hide(columns = c(Average_capxflow_1980,  Average_capxflow_1990,  Average_capxflow_2000,  Average_capxflow_2020,  Average_total_capxflow))|>
    fmt_percent(
    decimals = 1
  )|>
  cols_label(
    newname = md("Sector"),
    Average_aqcflow_1980 = md("1980-1990"),
    Average_aqcflow_1990 = md("1991-2001"),
    Average_aqcflow_2000 = md("2002-2007"),
    Average_aqcflow_2020 = md("2008-2020"),
    Average_total_aqcflow = md("**Whole Period**")
  ) |>
    tab_header(
    title = md("**1980-2020 NFCs' Acquisition expenditure as % available cash flow in each sector**"),
    subtitle = md("Ranked by average of whole period (last column in bold)")
  )|>
  tab_source_note(source_note = "Source: Compustat")|>
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = "Available funds is equal to operating income minus taxes plus new debt minus redemnted debt.",
    locations = cells_title(groups = "title")
    )|>
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = Average_total_aqcflow,
      rows = Average_total_aqcflow < 100
    )
  )|>
tab_style(
  style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
  locations = cells_body(
    rows = 8)
)
```

Here the data I am using. I want a that each sector takes three rows in the table and each of the rows describe the values of

```
dput(df)
structure(list(fyear = c(2006L, 1991L, 1982L, 2001L, 1993L, 1995L, 
1993L, 2002L, 2008L, 2014L, 2014L, 2005L, 1999L, 1984L, 2006L, 
2005L, 2013L, 2013L, 1984L, 2004L, 1992L, 2000L, 2003L, 1996L, 
2013L, 1986L, 1982L, 2012L, 2002L, 1999L, 2013L, 1995L, 2017L, 
2018L, 1993L, 1994L, 2018L, 2002L, 2006L, 1997L, 1980L, 2002L, 
1987L, 1988L, 2001L, 1988L, 1999L, 1995L, 1998L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2006L, 2005L, 2000L, 2011L, 1987L, 2005L, 1996L, 2017L, 1983L, 
2019L, 2018L, 1990L, 2011L, 2001L, 1995L, 2018L, 2010L, 1985L, 
1992L, 2016L, 1981L, 1995L, 2009L, 2013L, 2020L, 2011L, 1990L, 
2010L, 1983L, 2010L, 2015L, 1982L, 1981L, 1991L, 2014L, 1980L, 
1992L, 2001L, 1988L, 1986L, 2011L, 2009L, 2011L, 2006L, 1995L, 
2008L, 2004L, 2001L, 2003L, 2003L, 1989L, 1999L, 2012L, 2015L, 
1986L, 1987L, 1993L, 2005L, 2017L, 2020L, 1994L, 1992L, 2003L, 
1988L, 1980L, 1992L, 2018L, 2010L, 2009L, 1995L, 2003L, 1996L, 
2009L, 2013L, 2012L, 2006L, 2008L, 1997L, 2004L, 1983L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2007L, 2011L, 2010L, 1996L, 2003L, 1990L, 2002L, 1990L, 
2016L, 1989L, 2017L, 2018L, 2010L, 2011L, 1996L, 2013L, 1990L, 
2000L, 2007L, 2020L, 1982L, 2018L, 2014L, 2007L, 2000L, 2017L, 
2008L, 2018L, 2011L, 2007L, 2009L, 1989L, 1988L, 2005L, 1997L, 
2007L, 1994L, 1985L, 1988L, 2014L, 1990L, 2003L, 1987L, 2004L, 
2003L, 2010L, 1994L, 1982L, 2019L, 2012L, 1982L, 1989L, 2001L, 
2019L, 1990L, 1994L, 2016L, 1991L, 1985L, 2017L, 2014L, 2011L, 
1995L, 1993L, 2003L, 2000L, 2010L, 2018L, 1997L, 1985L, 2003L, 
2010L, 1990L, 2012L, 1996L, 1988L, 2012L, 1985L, 1986L, 2015L, 
1992L, 2000L, 2012L, 2018L, 2000L, 1989L, 1998L, 2008L, 1994L, 
2006L, 1992L, 2015L, 1985L, 1985L, 2015L, 2001L, 1985L, 2014L, 
1988L, 2009L, 2013L, 1992L, 2018L, 1998L, 2005L, 1998L, 2012L, 
2012L, 1994L, 2018L, 1993L, 1997L, 2012L, 2009L, 1997L, 1987L, 
1996L, 2013L, 1996L, 2005L, 2014L, 2014L, 2006L, 1988L, 1997L, 
1994L, 2019L, 2002L, 2001L, 1991L, 2001L, 2000L, 1992L, 1983L, 
1997L, 2008L, 2020L, 1990L, 2010L, 1990L, 2019L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1992L, 1999L, 2002L, 1988L, 2014L, 2002L, 1986L, 1984L, 2014L, 
2008L, 2015L, 1986L, 2019L, 1988L, 1994L, 1993L, 2007L, 2018L, 
1994L, 2011L, 1994L, 1984L, 2002L, 1991L, 1983L, 1980L, 2000L, 
2011L, 2016L, 2005L, 1987L, 1984L, 1985L, 2013L, 2000L, 2002L, 
1989L, 2011L, 1992L, 1996L, 1987L, 1997L, 2010L, 2011L), newname = c("Utilities", 
"Telecom", "Services", "Energy", "Hitech", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"Services", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Consumer Durables", "Manufacturing", 
"Mining", "Transportation", "Manufacturing", "Wholesale & Retail", 
"Manufacturing", "Consumer Durables", "Utilities", "Hitech", 
"Consumer Non-Durables", "Transportation", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"Mining", "Manufacturing", "Transportation", "Hitech", "Healthcare", 
"Manufacturing", "Wholesale & Retail", "Mining", "Services", 
"Energy", "Wholesale & Retail", "Telecom", "Healthcare", "Energy", 
"Healthcare", "Transportation", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"Manufacturing", "Utilities", "Energy", "Energy", "Telecom", 
"Wholesale & Retail", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Mining", "Mining", 
"Wholesale & Retail", "Healthcare", "Transportation", "Transportation", 
"Hitech", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Transportation", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Wholesale & Retail", "Services", "Wholesale & Retail", "Services", 
"Healthcare", "Hitech", "Manufacturing", "Utilities", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"Wholesale & Retail", "Utilities", "Hitech", "Mining", "Healthcare", 
"Telecom", "Telecom", "ConstructionRealState", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Consumer Non-Durables", "Manufacturing", "Hitech", "Healthcare", 
"Consumer Durables", "Transportation", "Services", "Services", 
"Energy", "ConstructionRealState", "Transportation", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Mining", "Wholesale & Retail", "Healthcare", "Energy", "Energy", 
"Healthcare", "Utilities", "Energy", "Telecom", "Services", "Transportation", 
"ConstructionRealState", "Telecom", "Wholesale & Retail", "Consumer Durables", 
"Consumer Durables", "Manufacturing", "Mining", "Telecom", "Utilities", 
"Services", "Services", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Utilities", 
"Hitech", "Hitech", "Transportation", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"Services", "Transportation", "Consumer Durables", "Consumer Durables", 
"ConstructionRealState", "Consumer Durables", "Manufacturing", 
"Transportation", "Healthcare", "Telecom", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"ConstructionRealState", "Consumer Durables", "Telecom", "Mining", 
"Consumer Non-Durables", "Telecom", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"Consumer Durables", "Mining", "Telecom", "Transportation", "Consumer Durables", 
"Healthcare", "Healthcare", "Utilities", "Energy", "Wholesale & Retail", 
"Healthcare", "Hitech", "Wholesale & Retail", "Transportation", 
"Services", "Hitech", "Transportation", "Energy", "Manufacturing", 
"Energy", "Consumer Durables", "Transportation", "Hitech", "Utilities", 
"Transportation", "Energy", "Manufacturing", "Telecom", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Consumer Non-Durables", "Healthcare", "Transportation", "Mining", 
"Hitech", "Energy", "ConstructionRealState", "Consumer Durables", 
"Consumer Durables", "Hitech", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Consumer Durables", 
"Mining", "Telecom", "Healthcare", "Consumer Durables", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Energy", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Services", "Energy", "Healthcare", 
"Energy", "Telecom", "Telecom", "ConstructionRealState", "Telecom", 
"Manufacturing", "ConstructionRealState", "Utilities", "Services", 
"ConstructionRealState", "ConstructionRealState", "Utilities", 
"Utilities", "ConstructionRealState", "Transportation", "Healthcare", 
"Telecom", "Transportation", "Energy", "Manufacturing", "Utilities", 
"ConstructionRealState", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Energy", "Transportation", 
"Mining", "Consumer Durables", "Consumer Durables", "Telecom", 
"Wholesale & Retail", "ConstructionRealState", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Manufacturing", "Mining", "Consumer Durables", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Consumer Durables", "Manufacturing", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Mining", "Utilities", "Consumer Non-Durables", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Hitech", "Consumer Durables", "Manufacturing", "Healthcare", 
"Hitech", "Utilities", "Services", "Consumer Durables", "Transportation", 
"Mining", "Telecom", "Healthcare", "Mining", "Hitech", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Mining", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Healthcare", "Transportation", 
"Manufacturing", "Services", "Manufacturing", "Mining", "Hitech", 
"ConstructionRealState", "Hitech", "Healthcare", "ConstructionRealState", 
"Hitech", "Energy", "Telecom", "ConstructionRealState", "Energy", 
"Hitech", "ConstructionRealState", "Mining", "Hitech", "Services", 
"Utilities", "Hitech", "Consumer Non-Durables", "Transportation", 
"Services", "Energy", "Wholesale & Retail", "Hitech", "Consumer Non-Durables", 
"Hitech", "Energy", "Manufacturing", "Consumer Durables", "Wholesale & Retail", 
"Transportation", "Consumer Durables", "Mining", "Utilities", 
"Services", "Telecom", "Services", "Energy", "Manufacturing", 
"ConstructionRealState", "Manufacturing", "Energy", "Consumer Durables", 
"Wholesale & Retail", "Wholesale & Retail", "Telecom", "Hitech", 
"Consumer Durables", "Manufacturing", "ConstructionRealState", 
"ConstructionRealState", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Hitech", 
"Services", "Manufacturing", "Transportation", "Transportation", 
"Services", "Hitech", "Consumer Durables", "Transportation", 
"Utilities", "Transportation", "Manufacturing", "Mining", "Services", 
"Telecom", "Telecom", "Utilities", "Wholesale & Retail", "ConstructionRealState"
), decile = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), share_acq = c(0.191542651274958, 0.265140321777357, 
0.706493725732936, 0.586026909725353, 0.412705141382553, 0.697356513882913, 
0.29622430864106, 0.710837168647643, 0.485239094839832, 0.51552049942812, 
0.3396349683072, 0.520146556281163, 0.290540148583861, 0.263158122738678, 
0.30762535684379, 0.0571414035053517, 0.366068778883804, 0.50855828093791, 
0.493118823831736, 0.398834213477499, 0.651116633658315, 0.0165102954707569, 
0.278792266411379, 0.531080870425891, 0.295676654126381, 0.212000566942593, 
0.254798293239695, 0.153010856866212, 0.309512776994573, 0.352588520969021, 
0.00241608557025276, 0.513224744284108, 0.569441073026392, 0.422360239792212, 
0.938796810994834, 0.191793588856069, 0.240467451014162, 0.076789691094833, 
0.357217829509659, 0.492826324086685, 0.422363661339805, 0.0256046302993428, 
0.000281734840131089, 0.393415132777385, 0.371615416215594, 0.0430833932156499, 
0.381366610168104, 0.429216730959905, 0.274447660474304, 0.851546441279268, 
0.149063504195309, 0.393235237216426, 0.313010703878301, 0.0664344799567497, 
0.25744503650922, 0.608002542911634, 0.205690351177761, 0.340733346180276, 
0.302899082104837, 0.111709920392542, 0.00276136360972078, 0.371164027310566, 
0.566223843367427, 0.460362496925983, 0.54860895885306, 0.174214555651092, 
0.516980628683584, 0.149924353108916, 0.586078855163711, 0.486226032974547, 
0.559433669519736, 0.0878961082868067, 0.687335892853203, 0.0133463831301717, 
0.193169127240163, 0.412175196623609, 0.391529035079641, 0.286402074711966, 
0.10567713692789, 0.935628722450723, 0.473115178904375, 0.229206038386913, 
0.908128079113975, 0.0334372391094134, 0.426820217955731, 0.163577004249995, 
0.233548398581943, 0.296790224486965, 0.736504954811368, 0.00163442228058048, 
0.0099839473787244, 0.54072109614198, 0.0696880356965121, 0.152055813422504, 
0.339152444377713, 0.635891138115901, 0.422094995425012, 0.0818775544830965, 
0.387127549996544, 0.508075128781767, 0.57125927885229, 0.704457990869468, 
0.15339900221663, 0.158758203008148, 0.0810983663545707, 0.0818571610111656, 
0.710706363123992, 0.13506711409396, 0.10581397471149, 0.223703113813118, 
0.499856804687177, 0.173653025058064, 0.0318599583096456, 0.262131590981012, 
0.432506462976964, 0.0482864702737479, 0.336442688418006, 0.35005730573924, 
0.134873259702747, 0.69699851070817, 0.376081433304231, 0.532572301987086, 
0.483927765122696, 0.091340255011543, 0.197566874709687, 0.304451553904161, 
0.0696576747974658, 0.257609311324194, 0.160312984894085, 0.374424784353026, 
0.118234711192561, 0.149822734070739, 0.307247106846148, 0.120498956809659, 
0.651713530433249, 0.273376705417507, 0.595333302675237, 0.21877198431815, 
0.147136440527774, 0.50743431632638, 0.00446500931229682, 0.152680781132837, 
0.708464743663528, 0.392067318711486, 0.0576911173744673, 0.521505214904843, 
0.388184162597973, 0.453983479824338, 0.337350829395655, 0.83310039848679, 
0.579101473859919, 0.720518761249022, 0.14909059712451, 0.875617456944349, 
0.425343971643206, 0.578225279726103, 0.487970756888827, 0.0190490946005934, 
0.158127659947543, 0.0658700621422192, 0.554391058754075, 0.490016929465621, 
0.272434429767256, 0.463880451646537, 0.542031897684764, 0.462213708251502, 
0.685411335695317, 0.344521494905706, 0.150806590114351, 0.409180810706048, 
0.509163020685952, 0.156192769028631, 0.146095285128523, 0.545146426060826, 
0.301759867800809, 0.559498330739378, 0.803724913941913, 0.164441628653489, 
0.38493672602566, 0.341505537853976, 0.199538574081369, 0.596725288964987, 
0.239049139838664, 0, 0.523455132214846, 0.440555853240772, 0.365248426258993, 
0.320531665013033, 0.331737291523244, 0.322580626207454, 0.157006479502395, 
0.505088561620488, 0.369460956899522, 0.68666418251598, 0.119348488185917, 
0.0829425266377912, 0.0721121132714664, 0.315167683917895, 0.58701220789305, 
0.573740041933839, 0.661411555007964, 0.048986106537539, 0.493730655935281, 
0.281156106709187, 0.45657315036097, 0.532946696688151, 0.6314165855914, 
0.382723577363017, 0.676895260931384, 0.141488728771754, 0.788322533225552, 
0.210540020949296, 0.0828919021157495, 0.63751501674207, 0.600626129426129, 
0.280783523407729, 0.549818293602106, 0.0174200405352239, 0.0153536370500881, 
0.107541596365847, 0.287862746454454, 0.39534805935004, 0.10653296702434, 
0.429792957458306, 0.0931821338627719, 0.993179098524132, 0.341428861655892, 
0.231031998279719, 0.340277168130371, 0.0392092379492576, 0.539462262541857, 
0.0472013909428392, 0.319080358830134, 0.32805551288594, 0.236668561682774, 
0.231430137910315, 0.567906487855786, 0.518981193488092, 0.128071541571137, 
0.335810343096279, 0.402382278020903, 0.0427839812271334, 0.260180831914082, 
0.616141270147763, 0.406159639831527, 0.186330046187354, 0.192192554385887, 
0.200209560762186, 0.104311369524953, 0.392355713628819, 0.435982165750096, 
0.153660806546842, 0.446538556975251, 0.149758813234025, 0.34765486211521, 
0.0124971007097463, 0.196507511057297, 0.385907371040073, 0.183197780688604, 
0.119815405858939, 0.363193204648433, 0.250921440210049, 0.187855283232397, 
0.326555234391177, 0.308342277106026, 0.187347250562444, 0.137517727326735, 
0.444504265590148, 0.103480472739266, 0.100394316353069, 0.137413870586059, 
0.543855513948405, 0.368397485662768, 0.578867393504293, 0.999240448208652, 
0.3317327099138, 0.598004099595557, 0.162211053358298, 0.0884051608927431, 
0.182780460424438, 0.317495325502826, 0.300144360856842, 0.271252529498976, 
0.405861027661594, 0.406303236138954, 0.342390096980172, 0.448581330606813, 
0.0388174476148426, 0.44213159045739, 0.272677229821136, 0.255119734509338, 
0.284090471660242, 0.430743263486527, 0.418343385739807, 0.551082513174983, 
0.229758366836472, 0.410869877653818, 0.204937787792691, 0.452868578515077, 
0.237958462183004, 0.493996276919085, 0.175643966589035, 0.1934701393654, 
0.495414103503546, 0.22134691493903, 0.394596425964314, 0.113955929689712, 
0.380380788763916, 0.0409916119011536, 0.276254440234794, 0.406335200804096, 
0.705128502591212, 0.127200893828246, 0.49732060481691, 0.113616423206304, 
0.563964516800517, 0.24671344388193, 0.363308595531241, 0.464159565923663, 
0.236361764024406)), row.names = c(NA, -320L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Since we don't know what's in `df4` right now, it's not clear what this code is producing.

Comment: Have you looked into the gtsummary package? https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/

Comment: I added the structute of the data. I hope that's helpful